# Согласование существительного

Tags: согласование

Как правильно:Таня была учительница. Или:Таня была учительницей.

Answer (score 3):

**1. Как решаются такие задачи**

Тема выбора творительного или именительного падежа для именной части сказуемого не так проста.

С одной стороны, лингвисты обозначили область применения для каждого случая. **Творительный падеж** обозначает признак, который может меняться во времени, он в большей степени книжный (литературный), также он более характерен для современного языка.

**Именительный падеж** обозначает вневременной (постоянный) признак, он чаще используется в разговорной речи, да и вообще вроде бы уступает свои позиции творительному падежу.

**Но писатели, как мне кажется, не очень прислушиваются к этим выводам,** у них свое понимание того, в чем различие И. п и Т.п. (Кстати, лингвисты подтверждают эту  "непоследовательность" в применении сформулированных ими правил).

Надо сказать, что выбор падежа **для прилагательных** более свободен, там чаще встречаются варианты, в то время как падеж **существительных** нормируется более строго. В частности, для связки ***быть*** в форме прошедшего времени (он был, она была) рекомендуется Т.п. Но можно привести **примеры из художественной литературы, в которых выбор сделан в пользу И.п.,** так что каждый случай индивидуален и формальным правилам подчиняется далеко не всегда.

**Примеры:**

Он ничего не приказывал, но **он был вожак**. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

...но **он был мой друг**, и по какому-то древнему закону товарищества, землячества, своячества или как там ещё я его должен был защищать... [Фазиль Искандер. Мой кумир (1965-1990)]

Но **он был наивный человек**, мой отец. [Анатолий Рыбаков. Тяжелый песок (1975-1977)]

Нюра засмеялась. **Она была очень смешливая женщина**. И смеялась как-то очень доверчиво и мило ― хотелось её смешить. [Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки (1970-1972)]

**2. Решение задачи**

***Таня была учительница. Таня была учительницей.*** Пишите как нравится, оба варианта верны?

Нет, пожалуй. Решить эту задачу без контекста сложно, поэтому надо как-то обозначить ситуацию.

(1) *Таня **была учительницей** в небольшом поселке и в город выбиралась не часто.*

(2) *Но Таня **была учительница**, и это сказывалось на ее характере.*

В первом предложении говорится об определенном периоде жизни героя (Т.п.). Во втором предложении сказуемое имеет вневременной характер, поэтому использован И.п.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта допустимы, первый устаревший (или устаревающий) и потому более "книжный". Второй общеупотребительный.